# webapp compiled with jdk8 running in Tomcat 7 where jdk7 is only installed

Tags: java, tomcat

I would like to know: 
would it work smoothly if a webapp compiled with jdk8 running in Tomcat 7 where JDK7 is only installed. 
This question is actually about java running procedure, so instead of yes or no, please explain a little. Thanks.

Comment: No, a class incorporating JDK8 features can't run on JDK7.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Would it be able to run if it didn't use any JDK 8 features?  Not that I'm suggesting the OP should go down this road, just curious.

Comment: @DenysSéguret what if in the same host of tomcat7, JDK 8 is installed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If it didn't use language features *or* the APIs. It'd have to be done with `-target 1.7`.

Comment: Today I have been through: Tomcat7 is jdk7, and if a war is compiled using jdk8, it would be "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError Unsupported major.minor version 51.0". UnsupportedClassVersionError is compiler version is higher than the runtime jdk version.